# chrome driver wont start session with given profile C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So i've been trying to start my selenium session with my own profile and here is my code:

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Mymsi\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
        options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\aliza\Downloads"); 
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

but for some reason selenium keeps starting a new session. Can someone tell me what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Initiate driver as in below code

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\aliza\Downloads", options);
```